# jquery TextExt with submit button doesn't POST hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've read the manual and followed all instructions, but it doesn't work :(

The data does get printed inside the hidden input (not hidden in the code for testing purpose). However, when i submit the form and try to var_dump the POST values, i can't see the tags from the hidden field.

I added another text field named "test" with the string "it works". This field does get POST'ed and appears in the var_dump ... But not the hidden field !

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$http = "https";
$domain = "ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"></script>
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.core.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.plugin.tags.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.plugin.autocomplete.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.plugin.focus.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.plugin.prompt.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/css/textext.plugin.arrow.css\" type=\"text/css\" />
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.core.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.tags.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.autocomplete.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.suggestions.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.filter.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.focus.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.prompt.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.ajax.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
        <script src=\"$http://www.$domain/scripts/js/textext.plugin.arrow.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>";

echo "<textarea id=\"textarea\" rows=\"1\" style=\"width:500px\"></textarea>
<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"POST\" id=\"tags_form\">
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $('#textarea').textext({
                    html: {
                       hidden: ('<input type=\"text\" name=\"tags\" style=\"position:relative; top:50px;\"/>')
                    },
                plugins : 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax arrow',
                tagsItems : [ 'Basic', 'JavaScript', 'PHP', 'Scala' ],
                prompt : 'Add one...',
                ajax : {
                    url : '$http://www.$domain/scripts/data.json',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    cacheResults : true
                }
            });
</script>
<br><br><br><input type=\"text\" name=\"test\" value=\"it works\">
<button type=\"submit\" form=\"tags_form\" value=\"Submit\">Submit</button>
</form>

";
echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: 1) use heredocs so you don't have to do all that ridiculous escaping. 2) try using a hidden form for you hidden input. 3) try closing the form. 4) idk this plugin but maybe it's puttng the input somewhere other than in the form. try to get the value with jquery on submit and add it to the form. `$("form").submit(function(){ $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='tags' value='"+$("input[name='tags']").val()+"'/>"); );`

Comment: The input was indeed outside of the form. Thanks ! Got it fixed now.

Comment: Shucks shoulda made  a answer.. glad to help